# Copy a XML subtag one level up

Tags: xmlstarlet

I need to change the structure of an XML file copying an sub tag one level up

```xml
<products>
  <product>
    <a>A content</a>
    <b>B content</b>
    <c>
      <d>d content</d>
      <e>e content</e>
    </c>
  </product>
  <product>
    <a>A content</a>
    <b>B content</b>
    <c>
      <d>d content</d>
      <e>e content</e>
    </c>
  </product>
</products>
```

to

```xml
<products>
  <product>
    <a>A content</a>
    <b>B content</b>
    <e>e content</e>
    <c>
      <d>d content</d>
      <e>e content</e>
    </c>
  </product>
  <product>
    <a>A content</a>
    <b>B content</b>
    <e>e content</e>
    <c>
      <d>d content</d>
      <e>e content</e>
    </c>
  </product>
</products>
```

**copying** e tag from c sub content to stand alone tag after b tag

using any terminal command

Comment: You just want to copy `<e>e content</e>` but **not** remove it from its original position?

Answer (score 0):

Using [xq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#xml-support):

The first solution is short and does not respect the order you wish.
The second solution respects the order you wish.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INPUT='
<products>
  <product>
    <a>A content</a>
    <b>B content</b>
    <c>
      <d>d content</d>
      <e>e content</e>
    </c>
  </product>
  <product>
    <a>A content</a>
    <b>B content</b>
    <c>
      <d>d content</d>
      <e>e content</e>
    </c>
  </product>
</products>
'

echo version 1
xq -x '.products.product |= map(. += {e: .c.e})' <<< "$INPUT"

echo
echo version 2
xq -x '.products.product |=
map(.c.e as $x
    | reduce to_entries[] as $p
             ({}; .[$p.key] = $p.value | if $p.key == "b" then .e = $x else . end)
   )
' <<< "$INPUT"
```

**Output**

```xml
version 1
<products>
  <product>
    <a>A content</a>
    <b>B content</b>
    <c>
      <d>d content</d>
      <e>e content</e>
    </c>
    <e>e content</e>
  </product>
  <product>
    <a>A content</a>
    <b>B content</b>
    <c>
      <d>d content</d>
      <e>e content</e>
    </c>
    <e>e content</e>
  </product>
</products>

version 2
<products>
  <product>
    <a>A content</a>
    <b>B content</b>
    <e>e content</e>
    <c>
      <d>d content</d>
      <e>e content</e>
    </c>
  </product>
  <product>
    <a>A content</a>
    <b>B content</b>
    <e>e content</e>
    <c>
      <d>d content</d>
      <e>e content</e>
    </c>
  </product>
</products>
```

Comment: It outputs the content and not a new xml structure

Comment: the output is shown in my answer and it is exactly what you ask for in your question

Comment: the output is: A content
B content

d content
e content



A content
B content

d content
e content
and not an XML structure...

Comment: The output is definitely an XML structure as shown - I have no clue what you are doing that the tags are lost on your machine. I have added my complete bash script including the output. Hope this helps you